# Why do we care about local derivations?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebras

I've been trying to study the lie algebra of derivations on a given associative, commutative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. The motivation for this is to study properties of a smooth manifold through studying the derivations on its algebra of smooth functions. In reviewing literature on derivations, I have found many papers on local derivations. For example, [this professor](https://twas.org/directory/ayupov-shavkat-abdullaevich) has local derivations as one of their research interests, and has dozens of papers on the subject.

For some background, a derivation is an $F$-linear operator on an $F$-algebra $D$ that satisfies the product rule $D(a\times b)=D(a)\times b+a\times D(b)$. A local derivation $L$ is a generalization of the concept of a derivation (and thus a bit of a misnomer, since it might not actually be a derivation) is an $F$-linear operator such that at each $a$ in the algebra, there is a derivation $D_a$ depending on $a$ that satisfies $L(a)=D_a(a)$. The main question in studying local derivations seems to be when they are derivations.

My question is: *Why do we care about local derivations?* Would they be connected to my research question of connecting the analytic properties of smooth manifolds with the algebraic properties of its lie algebra of derivations?